# Creating a Caesar Cipher Program in Python 3.4, but function doesn't work

Tags: function, python-3.x, encryption, typeerror

Currently, I am creating a Caesar Cipher but it is not working correctly, can anyone help at all? The code will be below. At the moment, if the program is run first time (as in, no functions have to be re run) it works perfectly, but when the getKey() function is re run, it returns an error. After the code, the error is shown:

```
def runProgram():
    def choice():
        userChoice = input("Do you wish to Encrypt of Decrypt? Enter E or D: ").lower()
        if userChoice == "e":
            return userChoice
        elif userChoice == "d":
            return userChoice
        else:
            print("Invalid Response. Please try again.")
            choice()

    def getMessage():
        userMessage = input("Enter your message: ")
        return userMessage

    def getKey():
        try:
            userKey = int(input("Enter a key number (1-26): "))
        except:
            print("Invalid Option. Please try again.")
            getKey()
        else:
            if userKey < 1 or userKey > 26:
                print("Invalid Option. Please try again.")
                getKey()
            else:
                return userKey

    def getTranslated(userChoice, message, key):
        translated = ""
        if userChoice == "e":
            for character in message:
                num = ord(character)
                num += key
                translated += chr(num)

                savedFile = open('Encrypted.txt', 'w')
                savedFile.write(translated)
            savedFile.close()
            return translated
        else:
            for character in message:
                num = ord(character)
                num -= key
                translated += chr(num)
            return translated

    userChoice = choice() #Runs function for encrypt/decrypt selection. Saves choice made.
    message = getMessage() #Run function for user to enter message. Saves message.
    key = getKey() #Runs function for user to select key. Saves key choice.
    translatedMessage = getTranslated(userChoice, message, key) #Runs function to translate message, using the choice, message and key variables)
    print("\nTranslation complete: " + translatedMessage)
runProgram()
```

I have tried to create it error proof during the getKey() function with the try, except and else commands. It will 'Try' to see that the input is an int or not, if it is, it goes to else, but if it isn't an int, then it will rerun the function. If the function is rerun, and an int is entered, this error is given:

This is an example of it working:

```
Do you wish to Encrypt of Decrypt? Enter E or D: E

Enter your message: Hello
Enter a key number (1-26): 5

Translation complete: Mjqqt
```

This is an example when the getKey() function must be re run due to an int not being entered:

```
Do you wish to Encrypt of Decrypt? Enter E or D: E

Enter your message: Hello
Enter a key number (1-26): H
Invalid Option. Please try again.
Enter a key number (1-26): 5

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python34\Encryptor2.py", line 54, in 
    runProgram()
  File "C:\Python34\Encryptor2.py", line 52, in runProgram
    translatedMessage = getTranslated(userChoice, message, key) #Runs function to translate message, using the choice, message and key variables)
  File "C:\Python34\Encryptor2.py", line 35, in getTranslated
    num += key

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

As you can see, it re runs the function as I want it too, but the error occurs when adding the key to the ord of character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first call to getKey(), with your comment:

```
key = getKey() #Runs function for user to select key. Saves key choice.
```

Another place you call it:

```
        if userKey < 1 or userKey > 26:
            print("Invalid Option. Please try again.")
            getKey()
```

If you were to write that with the same kind of comment, it would be:

```
            getKey() #Runs function for user to select key. Doesn't save key choice.
```

What the user types in, comes out of getKey() ... and you aren't keeping track of it, so it vanishes. You then do.

```
            return userKey
```

userKey is still the `H` you tried to convert to int, the one that failed. You didn't get rid of it, so it's still there.

The better solution is to rework the shape of your code, so getKey() never calls getKey() inside itself. Do the error checking outside, perhaps, like this kind of shape:

```
def getKey():
    prompt user for key
    try to convert to int and return the int
    if it fails, return None as an indication that getting the key went wrong.

key = None  #set some wrong placeholder
while (key is None) or (key < 1) or (key > 26):
    key = getKey()
```

Comment: I had never used the return command before, and so never realised that would happen. Thanks, it really helped and is now working fine!

Answer (score 0):

change your input to raw_input

Answer (score 0):

just use the maketrans and translate functions that basically encrypt or decrypt the message for you.they make for a very short and efficient solution to  the problem

```
message = input('enter message').lower()
offset = int(input('enter offset (enter a negative number to decrypt)'))
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
enc_alphabet = (alphabet[alphabet.index(alphabet[offset]):len(alphabet)])+ alphabet[0:offset]
data = str.maketrans(alphabet,enc_alphabet)
final_message = str.translate(message, data)
print(final_message)
```

Answer (score -1):

This code really doesn't need to be this complicated at all, if you just use regex the code will be much shorter but (in my opinion) way better.

Here's a code I created for Caesar cipher encrypting, decrypting and using a shift of the user's choice using regex.

```
import re

def caesar(plain_text, shift):
    cipherText = ''
    for ch in plain_text:
      stayInAlphabet = ord(ch) + shift
      if ch.islower():
        if stayInAlphabet > ord('z'):
          stayInAlphabet -= 26
        elif stayInAlphabet < ord('a'):
          stayInAlphabet += 26
      elif ch.isupper():
        if stayInAlphabet > ord('Z'):
          stayInAlphabet -= 26
        elif stayInAlphabet < ord('A'):
          stayInAlphabet += 26
      finalLetter = chr(stayInAlphabet)
      cipherText += finalLetter
    print(cipherText)
    return cipherText


selection = input ("encrypt/decrypt ")
if selection == 'encrypt':
  plainText = input("What is your plaintext? ")
  shift = (int(input("What is your shift? ")))%26
  caesar(plainText, shift)

else:
  plainText = input("What is your plaintext? ")
  shift = ((int(input("What is your shift? ")))%26)*-1
  caesar(plainText, shift)
```